# «За собой» или «с собой»?

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, морфология, предлоги

У меня назрел вопрос. Как правильно говорить: «унести С собой» или «унести ЗА собой»? Если это возможно, то поясните, пожалуйста, ответ.

Comment: Если вы про "унести с собой в могилу", то в словарях находится только вариант с предлогом "с". https://phraseology.academic.ru/13245/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%81_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B2_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%83

Answer (score 1):

Правильный вариант:

> *унести* (*увести* кого-то, *взять* что-то, *привести* кого-то и т. п.) ***с*** собой

Предлог **с** подразумевает здесь "***вместе (с собой)**. "Унести" значит "уйти с каким-то предметом, *взяв* его **с** собой".

Предлог "за" в сочетании с "собой" обозначает другое, а именно расположение (кого-либо) ***позади*** себя или движение кого-то, чего-либо ***вслед*** за собой:

> *повести **за** собой* людей, *тащить **за** собой* тележку

Answer (score 0):

Правильно  *унести с собой*. Это устойчивое словосочетание, а также часть фразеологизма [Унести с собой в могилу](https://phraseology.academic.ru/13245/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%81_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B2_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%83) . Чаще всего используется именно в значении данного фразеологизма, хотя есть и другие многочисленные примеры употребления:

*Тем не менее всякий из нас способен унести с собой копии всех встреченных и воспроизвести их в новом мире.* [Виктор Пелевин. Любовь к трем цукербринам (2014)] - пример из НКРЯ.

*За собой* можно *вести*:

*Человек попросту не имеет никакого морального и этического права вести за собой подобных ему, ― подводил итоги своей книги неистовый Франсуа.* [Илья Бояшов. Путь Мури (2007)] - Пример из НКРЯ.